# how to update a record in mysql through java

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently trying to code a java program for a school project that has a mysql database of sportsclub members. I want to use the id of the members in order to change the number of classes that someone skipped. However my Java code always fails to run and outputs the exception message. My database is called demo1 and the field im trying to update is Consecutiveskips. The id field is called (id)

[image]

Comment: Show the exception and add your code as text

Comment: You have to bind two parameters

Comment: Als the first number is the position where the Parameter should bind to

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to update record is through statement

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection oCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");

String query="Update Demo1 SET Consecutiveskips=? where id=?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = oCon.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 233);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 4);
```

In your code you are using setInt(6,1) but there is no 6th index present.
You should use

```
preparestaement.setInt(1,"yourconsicutiveskipvalue");
preparestaement.setInt(2,"idvalue");
```

Moreover, make sure to have mysql-connector.jar in classpath

Comment: You should use prepared Statements.

Comment: but he is new to jdbc, so asking simple way @jens

Comment: But the simplest way is not the best way. Prepared Statements will prevent for SQL-injection

Comment: I am quite new to Java DB access, but I think OP should look into JPA